# I need to find a safe website to get NST choir VST

Tags: vst

as well as a good harmonica VST that is free

and i REALLY want to get ahold of these.

I'm mainly saying that because i can't seem to find a website from the original manufacturer of said VST

NST CHOIR:

Comment: Regarding the question about harmonica, recommendations for specific products are off-topic.